# How to get first value and remaining as nulls in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like as follows

```
month    city     no_of_persons
-------------------------------
Apr-21   Hyd      12
Apr-21   Hyd      12 
Apr-21   Hyd      12
Apr-21   Bng      20
Apr-21   Bng      20
Apr-21   Bng      20
```

From the above data i am expecting the below result

```
month    city     no_of_persons
-------------------------------
Apr-21   Hyd      12
Apr-21   Hyd      null 
Apr-21   Hyd      null
Apr-21   Bng      20
Apr-21   Bng      null
Apr-21   Bng      null
```

i want to get the first not null value in the partition (month,city) and remaining values in the partition as nulls.

Could you guys help me on this.!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have duplicate rows in your table to begin with?  Something seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should normally be done in the application layer or by fixing the data so rows are not duplicated.  But you can do it in the database if you really want:

```
select month, city,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then no_of_persons end) as no_of_persons
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by month, city order by month) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by month, city, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `row_number` with `if`:

```
with mytable as (
  select 'Apr-21' as month, 'Hyd' as city, 12 as no_of_persons union all
  select 'Apr-21', 'Hyd', 12 union all
  select 'Apr-21', 'Hyd', 12 union all
  select 'Apr-21', 'Bng', 20 union all
  select 'Apr-21', 'Bng', 20 union all
  select 'Apr-21', 'Bng', 20
)
select 
  month,
  city,
  if(row_number() over (partition by city) = 1, no_of_persons, null) as no_of_persons
from mytable
```

[image]